# Printing multiple user input from a loop

Tags: java, loops, for-loop

This is a two part question. 1) how do I print all userinput if the loop runs more than once , I am aware the old string assigned to the variable gets erased each time. 2) how do i calculate the total task duration across all tasks for the amount of times the loop runs. thanks.

```
    public static String createTaskID()
    { 
       num1 = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null," Enter the number of tasks you wish to enter "));           
               
         for(i = 0;i<num1;i++){       
      taskName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(" Enter the name of task ");
     
     taskNumber =0; taskNumber++;
      
      taskDescription = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null," Enter a short description of the task. ");
           if(checkTaskDescription(taskDescription))  
           { JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null," Task successfully captured ");}
           else
           { JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null," Please enter a task description of less than 50 characters "); }
       
      developerDetails = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(" Enter First and last name of the Developer assigned to task. ");
      
      taskDuration = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(" Enter estimated duration of task (in hours) ");
    
     option2 = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, " Choose Status of task : \n Option 1)To Do \n Option 2)Done \n Option 3)Doing ")); 
    
    switch(option2)
        { case 1: 
               taskStatus = " To Do ";
            break; 
            
        case 2 :
              taskStatus = " Done ";
            break; 
            
        case 3 : 
              taskStatus = " Doing ";
            break;}

     
    }   
        return null;
    }
    
    
    
    
    public static String printTaskDetails()
{  
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null," TASK DETAILS \n -----------------------\n  Current Task Status : " + taskStatus + 
   "\n Developer Details : " + developerDetails + "\n Task Number : " + taskNumber + "\n Task Name : " + taskName +  
           "\n Task Description : " + taskDescription + "\n Task Duration : " + taskDuration + " hours.");  
return null;
}
```

Comment: Learn about collections and classes and arrays. Very basic stuff you should've learned before you even think about writing Swing code.

Comment: It's generally difficult to read, which doesn't make it any easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a `class` for this purpose, which will have data members for `taskStatus`, `developerDetails`, `taskNumber`, `taskName`, `taskDescription`, `taskDuration`. You can discern these properties into several classes if it makes sense (like a `class` for `Developer`, another for `Task`), but for the sake of simplicity I will assume that a developer will have a single class for now and I will call it `MyTask`.

So, if you create a `List` of `MyTask`, initialized like

```
List<MyTask> myTasks = new ArrayList<MyTask>();
```

just before the loop (don't forget to implement `MyTask` and `import` the packages you need for `List` and `ArrayList`) and then, inside the loop you instantiate upon each iteration a `MyTask` object, then you can do something like

```
myTasks.add(theMyTask);
```

again, don't forget to properly create `theMyTask`. At the end of `createTaskID`

```
return myTasks;
```

however, since it's a `List` now, modify the declaration of the method to

```
public static List<MyTask> createTaskID()
```

as well. And, when you intend to display it, just call the method, loop the result convert each of them into a `String` that looks like you indended, concatenate the resulting strings and display the result.

Comment: thanks alot appreciate it